# How retrieve responseJSON property of a jquery $.ajax object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this javascript:

```
$ajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'DBConnect.php',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) {},
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        dir(thrownError);
        dir(xhr);
        dir(ajaxOptions);
    }
});
console.dir($ajax);
console.dir($ajax.responseJSON);
```

console.dir($ajax) shows it has a property named responseJSON, but when I try to access it with $ajax.responseJSON it returns undefined:
[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need it, over what is provided to the `success` handler (which is the responseJSON anyway)

Comment: This will be undefined/empty until the ajax call (which is asynchronous) is completed. At that point you have access to it from the success method..

Comment: How do I get the response data out of the success callback?

Comment: @user1028270: You can't.  AJAX is *asynchronous*.  You can only access the data from the callbacks.  What you can do is use `.done()` to add another callback so you can access the JSON `$ajax.done(function(data){ console.log(data); });`.

Comment: Please review my answer - you can if you set `async` to false and go from there ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, of course it's undefined, because at the moment when you run `console` at last lines of your code, response hasn't yet came from the server.

`$.ajax` returns promise, which you can use to attach `done()` and `fail()` callbacks, where you can use all the properties that you see. And you have actually used callback `error` and `success`, and that's where you can run code and other functions that rely on data in the response.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this trick to get the response out:

```
jQuery.when(
    jQuery.getJSON('DBConnect.php')
).done( function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

It's late but hopefully will help others.

Answer (score 0):

The response, is the "data", in success... so you can access to that writing data[0], data[1], inside the success.

For example:

```
success: function(data) {
 alert(data[0]);
},
```

If you want this response, out of the success, you can set a variable outside, and try this:

```
success: function(data) {
 myVar = data;
},
```

Hope, this help.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it out of the success callback? I want to work with the data in another location in my script.

Comment: Hello, set a variable outside the ajax function, and in the success, asign the value of data, to this variable, so you can use this data in another location.

Answer (score -1):

For those who don't really mind if it's synchronous, like I was, you can do this:

```
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/form',
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function (xhr, type, exception) {
            // Do your thing
        }
    });

    if(data.status === 200)
    {
        $('#container').html(data.responseJSON.the_key_you_want);
    }
});
```

It runs through the motions, waits for a response from the Ajax call and then processes it afterwards if the status == 200, and inside the `error` function if something triggered an error.

Edit the options to match your situation. Happy coding :)

Comment: The synchronous solution is almost always the wrong one.

Comment: Yes, it's bad practice to use synchronous solutions for most use cases here. But +1 for being the only person to provide a complete working example answer. I think sometimes there's value in seeing how the synchronous examples work clearly, too.

Comment: I just read comments saying that sync is bad practice but nobody explains why, if the option exists is because there are situations where is needed