# Digging through JSON structure (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

1st time experimenting with JSON data and I was hoping to get some clarity on my issue.

when is use .getJSON on a local file I get a neat stucture like:

[image]

I have no problem getting the value I need (CustRep) with something like:

```
$.each( data.result, function( key, val ) { 
  //console.log(val.CustRep);    
  });
```

Now if I pull the same data source from a server I get something like this: 
[image]

I just can't figure out the correct way to go through this structure so I can access the results array I need.

Can anyone please help explain to a JS novice why I am getting different structures on what seems to be the same source and how to properly navigate the 2nd structure so I can get the values for each CustRep?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `data.responseJSON.result` ?

Comment: It rather looks as if in the second case, you're accessing the wrong object, namely the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How retrieve responseJSON property of a jquery $.ajax object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681221/how-retrieve-responsejson-property-of-a-jquery-ajax-object)

Comment: yes, but I am looking to get jsonData.responseJSON.result but everything I tried returned "undefined"

Comment: You'll have to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

You basically go about it the same way as before, just with error checks:

```
if (data.status === 200) { //This is good to have
   if (data.responseJSON && data.responseJSON.result) {
       var results = data.responseJSON.result;
       handleResults(results);
   }
}
```

Comment: The data seems to be undefinedand and the if check fails.  When I try:
console.log(jsonData); - Get the info from my screen shot
console.log(jsonData.status); - undefined 

I must be missing something really basic here o.O